# Structural risk minimization and SVMs

Tags: classification, svm

I know what is SRM but I didn't understand the relation between SRM and SVMs. Can anyone explain me this? Why they say that SVMs rely on a SRM approach?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

Structural risk minimization is the Vapnik's concept of learning which is conceptually similar to the other "minimum assumption approaches". In short words, most of the learning algorithms (in classification) try to find some mapping from input space to classes in such a way that this mapping behaves "well" on the training set (returns correct answers). It is however a known phenomena, that this is not enough to build a good model, as one could for example memorize all training examples and have a model with 0 training error. It will, however - behave badly on new examples (unseen observations). Structural risk minimization may be summarized as follows: "To find a good classifier, select the **simplest** one minimizing training error". In other words - it is preferable to have a **simple** model over a complex one. As the later makes more assumptions about the data "from thin air" (without actual training data to support this complexity). Vapnik proved that there is a strong relation between classifiers complexity (measured with so called "Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension") and their ability to perform well on unseen data (test points). This VC dimension is (loosely speaking) the measure of how big a sets of points in a given classifier, can perfectly classify all possible labels.

The concept of "risk" is simply the probability of making bad decisions "in the future" (when our model classifies new, unseen points). And "structural" concept is name for the model's complexity, adaptability to complex patterns.

And how is SVM related to this concept? Through margin maximization. It appears (and can be strictly proven) that maximization of the margin reduced the VC dimension, so we search for simpler and simpler models when margin is being maximized.